# Rows seemingly automatically deleted after insert

Tags: python, flask, azure-sql-database, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to simply be able to get and post to a table. My `db` is defined as `SQLAlchemy(app)` after having set some `app.config` fields with passwords and whatnot.

Retrieving data seems to work fine. If I `GET` the page, I get the expected result. However, `POST` doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw an exception, however. Everything works as it should, except no new records seem to appear in the database.

Weirdly enough, when I remove the line `return redirect('/projects')`, it seems to have actually added the new record exactly the way I wanted. However, when I refresh the page the record is gone again. Almost as if the record was correctly inserted but then automatically deleted. I have also tried printing the SQL and running it directly in the Azure portal, and once more it works without problems. What's going on here? My code is the following:

```
@app.route("/projects", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def projects_index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = db.session.execute(f"""
            INSERT INTO projects (name) VALUES ('{request.form['name']}')
        """)
        return redirect('/projects')

    db_result = db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM projects')
    projects = [dict(project) for project in db_result]
    return render_template('projects.html', projects = projects)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After insertion you need to commit the changes to database.

```py
@app.route("/projects", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def projects_index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = db.session.execute(f"""
            INSERT INTO projects (name) VALUES ('{request.form['name']}')
        """)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/projects')

    db_result = db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM projects')
    projects = [dict(project) for project in db_result]
    return render_template('projects.html', projects = projects)
```